# How to deregister bundle from sylius?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am new to symfony, I created sylius project using

```
./composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius-standard:0.12
```

Now i want to remove/deregister some bundles from sylius (search, promotion, shipping .. etc); Without removing admin functionality of remaining bundles. what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Every time I want to disable some of Sylius bundles, I usually cannot do it because of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
\src\Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Kernel\Kernel.php
```

And remove bundle, bundle i have do it and it's not easy for debug after

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
/your/application/path/app/AppKernel.php
```

and remove lines of the bundle you don't need anymore.

Comment: how can i retain admin functionality from core/web bundles for rest of bundles ?

Comment: @Sridher: I don't know Sylius bit I suppose that if those bundles are, someway, connected you can't unregister them freely.